# Can Google Drive act as a DB for Mobile App?

Tags: android, database, google-drive-api

I am planning to build an Android mobile App, while one of the requirements is that DB schemes will be hosted on Google Drive (xls, csv, json formats).
I was thinking to use Google Drive API for communicating between the mobile app and the DB files hosted on Google Drive.

Did anyone use this approach before and can clarify if this is feasible indeed?

Thank you!

Comment: Better use [Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore) or convert these files to SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Using the Google Drive API for your mobile app's database is not ideal:

Not designed for databases. It can be slow and inefficient for frequent read/write access. Granting access to a user's entire Drive can pose a security risk. I recommend considering local storage, SQLite or cloud databases like Firebase Realtime Database or Cloud Firestore.

If you still want to use it, the links below will help you.

https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/about-sdk?hl=tr
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rznYp43KLRc